# onKeyUp triggering too early

Tags: jquery, onkeyup

I have the following if statement in a jquery function triggered by `onKeyUp` in a `text input field`

```
if ( famcount < 3 ) {
    alert('number too small.');
} else if ( famcount > 10 ){
    alert('number too large.');
}
```

The problem is, if the user tries to type `10` it executes after the 1 and triggers the first alert. Any suggestions on a better way to trigger this event than `onKeyUp`?

Answer (score 2):

Don't make this check on every keystroke.

Use the `blur` event instead, and then check the value of the input.

A [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/Mxd97/) to demonstrate

Answer (score 2):

you could use the `.blur()` event.

Because even if the user is trying to enter 5 digits the keyup event is supposed to fire 5 times so that's normal.

Or you could bind the validation to on user submit.